# Calculator in Bison , and double or int values

Tags: compiler-construction, calculator, bison, yacc

I want to create a calculator using flex/bison. I have created the following `%union`:

```
%union{
     int intValue;
     double realValue;
     char * numType;
}
```

So when I want to reduce to a rule like `term: primary` I check the numType if it is "INT" or "REAL" and i do something like this:

```
$<realValue>$=$<realValue>1; $<numType>$=$<numType>1;
```

(the same thing for intValue). Now the problem is that when i have rules like:

```
term:
  expr '+' expr |
  expr '*' expr |                          
  ...
```

I have to check too many times if the terms are real or ints so as to put them into the $realValue$ or $intValue$. The question is: Is it possible or is there any feature of bison/yacc that can reduce all this checking?

For example something like

```
%type <intValue,realValue>
```

Where you can assign a type two values and then for example if you have a rule like this:

```
a: primary ;
```

From now on when a is used to reduce to another rule and a is accessed then the realValue or intValue (the one that has value) will be accessed.Or something like that.... ?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a C question -- no C does not have dynamic types like that, so as long as you are using bison to generate a C parser, you can't do that.  If instead you use C++, you can do some limited dynamic typing, but you can't put many C++ types in a `%union`, so that may cause other difficulties.

Also, note that the `%union` is a union -- you can only use one value in it at a time.  So when you do `$<realValue>$=$<realValue>1; $<numType>$=$<numType>1;`, the second assignment overwrites (and corrupts) the first.  If you want to store multiple values with a rule, you need to put a struct into your union:

```
%union {
    enum type_t { INT, DOUBLE } type;
    struct {
        type_t type;
        int value;
    } intval;
    struct {
        type_t type;
        double value;
    } floatval;
}
```

But as you note, checking the type tags all over the place is hard.

Comment: Can you please explain how I can use your union in the rules? With example of course.

Answer (score 1):

All bison/yacc do is generate a C program. They do not change the semantics of C. Unions are still unions, so they are only capable of holding *one* of their alternatives members, and furthermore there is no inherent way to tell which type is being contained.

So you cannot simultaneously hold an integer in `intValue` and also a `char*` in `numType`. It's one or the other, never both.

Bison doesn't forced you to use a `union` type for the semantic type. You could use your own [tagged union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) data structure. But bison's `<type>` mechanism won't help you; you'll need to do all the work yourself. (Although it's not a lot more work than what you're attempting; you'll end up writing things like:

```
expr: expr '+' expr { if ($1.type == INT && $3.type == INT) {
                        $$.type = INT;
                        $$.intValue = $1.intValue + $3.intvalue;
                      } else {
                        double v1 = $1.type == INT ? (double)$1.intValue
                                                   : $1.realValue;
                        double v2 = $3.type == INT ? (double)$3.intValue
                                                   : $3.realValue;
                        $$.type = REAL;
                        $$.realValue = v1 + v2;
                      }
                    }
```